# Validation using if statement using input binding in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, inputbinding

I am creating a reusable component for Input field. I created a Boolean tag named "IsValid" inside my typescript file to show validation message.

My typescript file

```
export class InputControlsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() IsValid;
  @Input() className;
  @Input() controlName;
  @Input() inputType;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Html File

```
<div>
  <input type="{{inputType}}" class="{{className}}" >
  <span class="error-message" *ngIf="!IsValid">This Field is required</span>
</div>
```

How it is being used

```
<div>
          <label>Name</label>
          <app-input-controls  inputType="text"  controlName="Address" className="form-control" IsValid = "false">
          </app-input-controls>
</div>
```

I am able to change the value of the Boolean tag of typescript file but the error message is not changing on change of the Boolean tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ngModel like `[(IsValid)]`,

If you use `ngModel`,your model is binding two way.

For example set your html

```
<app-input-validation  [inputType]="'text'"  [controlName]="Address" [className]="form-control" [(IsValid)]="isValidDate">
</app-input-validation>
```

You can set isValid property on parent component whenever you want.

Only write `this.isValidText=true;`

Please examine [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lgsjxr)

Answer (score 0):

change !IsValid to IsValid. it will work

```
  <div>
      <input type="{{inputType}}" class="{{className}}" >
      <span class="error-message" *ngIf="IsValid">This Field is required</span>
    </div>
```